# DbUpdateConcurrencyException updates entire object instead of just what changed

Tags: entity-framework-core

Ok so i have the following situation with entity framework core 7.

let's say we have a simple person object with 3 properties
ID
firstname
lastname
SqlTime  (time stamp in sql server)

the app to update the person objects are running on 2 computers.
cpu 1 opens person with ID of 1
cpu 2 opens person with ID of 1

cpu2 changes firstname to whatever and saves.

cpu 1 changes lastname to whatever and saves.  This generates a DbUpdateConcurrencyException since the timestamps don't match.

There's code i found to handle this:

```
foreach (var ent in e.Entries)
                    {
                        var clientValues = ent.Entity;
                        var databaseValues = ent.GetDatabaseValues();
                        if (databaseValues != null)
                        {
                            ent.OriginalValues.SetValues(databaseValues);
                        }

                        ent.CurrentValues.SetValues(clientValues);
                        return base.SaveChanges();
                    }
```

pretty straightforward, pulls the data from the db, updates the original values so the time stamps match, and reprocess the save.

works great in that regard.

BUT what it does do, is overwrite the changes from CPU 2's firstname change with CPU 1's data even though the cpu 1 change didn't touch the first name.

how can i handle this.

in this situation i'd like cpu 2's first name change to stick and cpu2's last name change to stick as well since they didn't touch the same db column.  Be even better if the cpu1's change save would save the last name and also pull the first name from the db since it's different and cpu 1 didn't change it.

if the 2 saves modify the same db property, i totally get the 2nd save "winning" since it just overwrote it, but when it's different properties, seems like it should be able to handle it better.

is that possible?  not sure how to do that.
is there something built into EF core 7 that does that automatically?

I tried various properties trying to figure out just what properties changed between the 2 but i haven't had any luck making it work.